# Change background linear gradient Button style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change Button's background linear gradient color,

the maintain code if Border.Background,

for Case 1

[image]

to impletenment must fix as follow

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
```

for case 2

[image]

to impletenment must fix as follow

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0.5" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
```

How can I fix the Border.Background, to staticresource relation to

button style in xaml file

11/28 Update

I want to create 2 normal button, at the same application

how to using the key keyword to handle Border.Background.

As follow is whole code of button style

```
<!-- Button -->
    <Style x:Key="ButtonW2B" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            x:Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="2"
            BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.BorderBrush> <!--外框顏色-->
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.5" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                        <!--<Border.Background>-->
                        <!--按鍵底色-->
                        <!--<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>-->

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderDarkColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderLightColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                  (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, you want to implement different background changes on mouseover, based on the normal background?

Comment: No, I want put normal style button of both, in same application, so how can I fix the Border.Background.

Comment: Sorry, there is some sort of misunderstanding, I really don't get what you want to do. Maybe you can create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?